# Why ng-repeat is not working?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

ng-repeat not working with table,in the output only header part displayed?
As i think the binding i did is perfectly fine, but something is there which i am missing?
Can anyone help me out where i am doing wrong?

JAVA SCRIPT:

```js
var myapp=angular.module("MyApp",[]);
var controller=function($scope)
{ 
        var technology1=[
            {Name: "C#",Likes: 0,Dislikes: 0},
            {Name: "JAVA",Likes:0,Dislikes:0},
            {Name: "Python",Likes:0,Dislikes:0}
        ];
        $scope.technology=technology1;
        $scope.incrementLikes=finction(technology)
        {
            technology.Likes++;
        }
        $scope.discrementLikes=function(technology)
        {
        technology.Dislikes++;
        }
}
myapp.controller('MyController',controller);
```

```html
    <html ng-app="MyApp">
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <script src="angular.js"></script>
        <script src="Day2.js"></script>

    </head>
    <Body ng-controller="MyController">
    <div >
        <table border='2'>
        <thead> 
            <tr>
            <th>Name Of Technology</th>
            <th>Likes</th>
            <th>Dislikes</th>
            <th>Likes/Dislikes</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="tech in technology">
            <td>{{tech.Name}}</td>
            <td>{{tech.Likes}}</td>
            <td>{{tech.Dislikes}}</td>
            <td>
            <input type="button" value="Like" ng-click="incrementLikes(tech)">
            <input type="button" value="Dislikes" ng-click="decrementLikes(tech)">
            </td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    </Body>
    </html>
```

Comment: there is typo `finction` should be `function`

Answer (score 0):

Replace this line

```
        $scope.incrementLikes=finction(technology)
```

by

```
        $scope.incrementLikes=function(technology)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code has a typo in your `myController` controller. Change `finction` to `function`.

Answer (score 0):

As Pankaj Parkar pointed out you need to correct the "finction" typo as well as to reference the $scope.technology.Likes and $scope.technology.dislikes when you are incrementing their values.

So update these lines:

```
$scope.incrementLikes=finction(technology)
    {
        technology.Likes++;
    }
$scope.discrementLikes=function(technology)
    {
    technology.Dislikes++;
    }
```

To this

```
$scope.incrementLikes=function(technology)
    {
        $scope.technology.Likes++;
    }
$scope.discrementLikes=function(technology)
    {
        $scope.technology.Dislikes++;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the fully corrected code.  I can't comment on the answer from @pzelenovic but do NOT add "$scope.technology.Likes++;" or "$scope.technology.Likes++;" to your increment/decrement functions.  Those are fine the way they are because you're updating the likes/dislikes property on the "tech" object you passed in from the click function.

```js
var myapp=angular.module("MyApp",[]);
var controller=function($scope)
{ 
        var technology1=[
            {Name: "C#",Likes: 0,Dislikes: 0},
            {Name: "JAVA",Likes:0,Dislikes:0},
            {Name: "Python",Likes:0,Dislikes:0}
        ];
        $scope.technology=technology1;
        $scope.incrementLikes=function(technology)
        {
            technology.Likes++;
        }
        $scope.decrementLikes=function(technology)
        {
        technology.Dislikes++;
        }
}
myapp.controller('MyController',controller);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<html ng-app="MyApp">
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <script src="angular.js"></script>
        <script src="Day2.js"></script>

    </head>
    <Body ng-controller="MyController">
    <div >
        <table border='2'>
        <thead> 
            <tr>
            <th>Name Of Technology</th>
            <th>Likes</th>
            <th>Dislikes</th>
            <th>Likes/Dislikes</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="tech in technology">
            <td>{{tech.Name}}</td>
            <td>{{tech.Likes}}</td>
            <td>{{tech.Dislikes}}</td>
            <td>
            <input type="button" value="Like" ng-click="incrementLikes(tech)">
            <input type="button" value="Dislikes" ng-click="decrementLikes(tech)">
            </td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    </Body>
    </html>
```